# Confusion related to permutohedral lattice

Tags: geometry, lattice-orders

I was referring to this [paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/permutohedral/permutohedral_techreport.pdf&ei=XFVGUOmqGoTy0gGVjYCwDw&usg=AFQjCNGBdVr27F8eROwdrfiSrskQWULtJg&sig2=ozsqh2j5SXHjqGgtIe0Fpg) related to permutohedral lattice.

It states that the permutohedral lattice

$$
A_{d^*}= \bigcup_{k=0}^{d}\{\vec{x}\in H_d\ |\ \vec{x}\text{ is a remainder-$k$ point}\}
$$

Where we call $\vec{x} \in H_d$ a remainder-$k$ point for some $k \in \{0, \dots , d\}$ iff all coordinates are congruent to $k$ modulo $d+1$.

I didn't get what this remainder-$k$ point means or being congruent to $k$ module $d+1$ means. I am just a beginner. I didn't get how the permutohedral lattice equation came to be like that in the end. Any suggestions?